# Collapsing rows in multiindex dataframe with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like that:

```
        Date installed Date removed
ID Type                            
A  AA       2008-07-15   2008-12-29
   AA       2008-12-29   2009-10-15
   AAB      2009-10-15   2010-08-27
   AAB      2014-11-13   2015-04-28
```

and I want to collapse rows with same `'Type'` index and have minimum date in `'Date installed'` column and  maximum date in '`Date removed'` column. How can i do that?

Desired output:

```
        Date installed Date removed
ID Type                            
A  AA       2008-07-15   2009-10-15
   AAB      2009-10-15   2015-04-28
```

and code:

```
data = {'ID':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'Type':['AA', 'AA', 'AAB', 'AAB'], 'Date installed': ['2008-07-15',
'2008-12-29', '2009-10-15', '2014-11-13'], 'Date removed': ['2008-12-29', '2009-10-15', '2010-08-27', '2015-04-28']}
df.set_index(['ID', 'Type'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by dictionary for aggregate `min` and `max`:

```
df[['Date installed','Date removed']] = df[['Date installed','Date removed']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg({'Date installed':'min', 'Date removed':'max'})
print (df)
        Date installed Date removed
ID Type                            
A  AA       2008-07-15   2009-10-15
   AAB      2009-10-15   2015-04-28
```